# Checking if 8 points in the projective plane lie on a singular cubic.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, cubics, singularity, finite-geometry

I need to check if 8 points of $\mathbb{P}^2$ (over a finite field) lie on a singular cubic with one of them a double point.

I know that to check if a point is singular we suffice to compute the partial derivatives in it and look if they are all 0.

I also know I can use the Veronese embedding to prove that 10 points of $\mathbb{P}^2$ are independent with regard to cubics, i.e. don't lie in one, if and only if the matrix that has as rows the evaluation of monomials of degree 3 in a given point has rank 10.

However I'm not sure how to unite the two concepts to find an easy (as in "easy to feed to a computer to check") condition to check if there is a singular cubic passing through the 8 points and having a singularity in one of them.

My idea is to use a matrix that has the following rows:

- rows 1-7 evaluation of monomials of degree 3 in each of 7 points
- rows 8-10 the partial derivatives to such monomials evaluated in the 8-th point

Repete 8 times changing the point we want to check is singular.

But I can't find a proper proof that this does actually work.

Comment: Here is an idea. Suppose the 8 points impose independent conditions. Then the space of cubics passing through these points is 2-dimensional. Get a basis say given by equations  $f_1$ and $f_2$. Then all you need to check is whether the vectors of partial derivatives $\nabla f_1$, $\nabla f_2$, at one of  these $8$ points are linearly dependent or not.

Comment: Also checking 8 points impose independent conditions on cubics is easy geometrically: you need that any $5$ do not lie on a line, or all $8$ do not lie on a conic.

Comment: This indeed works but does my method also work?
Because checking if two vectors are independent may be not as easy as checking if a matrix has a zero determinant in my case

Comment: Your method also works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the end the method I proposed actually works